# Android audio equalizer

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, fft, equalizer

I am working on an Android application which should work like Digital Equalizer. It should have 10 channels with Volume (level in) and Gain (level out). It should have ability to perform Fast Fourier Transform of audio stream ranging from 5 to 192kHz (for 24bit encoding).

For the Equalizer, I have tried with `android.media.audiofx.Equalizer`. But, I found that it is providing 5 bands and which cannot be extended to 10 bands. As well there is not much detail to change audio frequency manually. Is there any way to change the frequency and apply it to the audio? Any help on it and FFT will be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest you roll up your sleeves and find any FFT api out there ... teach yourself how prepare audio to be feed into a FFT call and how to parse the output from that call ... armed with that knowledge will then be free to choose any number of channels not necessarily 10 channels and you will begin to admire the sheer magic behind a Fourier Transform ... have fun ... remember a software engineer needs to reach a level of independence to feel free to actually write code not simply to glue together endless api calls ... by some accounts all the real magic happens behind those api calls